# Why does Ubuntu 9.04 console not work with Windows 7 Windows Virtual PC?

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-virtual-pc, grub, console

Here's a screen shot of my console in an Ubuntu 9.10 desktop live CD installed onto a Windows 7 Windows Virtual PC machine, and then stripped of the X/gnome environment:

[image]

Note that the Grub part works fine (I edited /etc/default/grub to use console for output). Once the kernel loads, it switches the graphics card somehow into this dumb mode. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: good question.  just ran into this issue myself, using VirtualPC on winXP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough "karma" to post comments, but in addition to VirtualBox (which is awesome, BTW), there's also a slew of VMWare products that will do the same for free. VMWare Server and Player both create and run virtual machines, and are pretty reliable.

[This link](http://blogs.zdnet.com/hardware/?p=273) is from 2007, but the short story is no, the graphics are too messed up... and possibly by design.

*<conspiracy theory>After all, why would MS want you to run anything linux related using their software?</conspiracy theory>*

Comment: Agreed, MS VPC is a gross incarnation, even the BIOS file has invalid values (via a hex editor), and spawns bugs in Knoppix as well. For VMWare Player use http://www.easyvmx.com to create machines.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me (under Vista but I assume it will work for Win7):

edit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist

add the line”blacklist s3fb”

save

reboot

Comment: This actually worked. Details: Windows Virtual PC 2007 SP1; running on Windows XP SP3; running Ubuntu Desktop 9.10 32bit; before applying this hack the console looked like the screenshot above. After applying this hack the console looks like http://i42.tinypic.com/2yzeigw.png

Answer (score 0):

Recent kernels switched to framebuffer devices, maybe the virtual pc cannot cope with that. Two solutions:

- try the free-as-in-beer VirtualBox emulation software instead
- try the Ubuntu server flavour install iso, which IIRC comes without windowing environments

Comment: Actually, I'm trying WVPC as a replacement for VirtualBox, which had some issues with my laptop.
Are the ubuntu kernels so different that server does text mode, and desktop cannot?
I suppose I can switch kernels using apt-get :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `vga=normal` to your kernel command line.